# (Error firebase analytics in ionic) ERROR TypeError: Object(…) is not a function

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework, mobile

I have this problem with my ionic project. Already installed the necessary plugins for firebase analytics, I have already followed tutorials to integrate it with my app, created the services, added in app.module.ts and did all those steps. But when I click the button to test the tagging, it gives this error in the browser console. I have tried some solutions but no solution completed yet. Can someone help me please?

**Error:**

```
TypeError: Object(…) is not a function
```

Comment: What plugin are you using?